# Assign array elements randomly but ensure that all are used?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can the assignment of array elements into different objects be randomised such that

- there's **no recycling** of array elements (i.e. the same array element is never used more than once, unless it was a duplicate), and
- **all values get used**, including duplicates. The resulting number of objects created should be the same as the length of the array
- it works for array elements that aren't necessarily single integers

#### Example

An array `[1, 2]` would have two possible outcomes:

1. a = 1 and b = 2, OR
2. a = 2 and b = 1.

An array of `[1, 2, 3]` would have 6 possible outcomes.

#### Use case

I want to randomly sample inputs to a rails mailer preview, but the inputs aren't all of the same class, so I can't do something like `Customer.all.sample`

I also can't simply combine the possible inputs into an array and sample from it, since that could cause the same element to get used more than once.

Comment: What does `a` and `b` mean in your example?

Comment: @user1934428 a and b in my real use case where 'to' and 'from' in some mailer previews. Basically an app with patients and physicians and I didn't want the previews to always be from patient to physician or always from physician to patient, but instead to randomise to get more 'real world' email previews

Answer (score 2):

`.sample` will sample **without replacement** by default.

So, for example,

```rb
arr = [1, 2, 3]

a, b, c = arr.sample(arr.length)

a
=> 3

b
=> 1

c
=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) is another option, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1].shuffle
```

produces `[3, 2, 1, 1, 1]`, `[1, 1, 2, 3, 1]`, ...